# Return true false or some data When Time falls in Time Range in a chain of Time Ranges?

Tags: c#

I have Time Ranges in the day where an activity is allowed/forbidden. 
I prepared a tiny class that can hold the time ranges that cover the day.
The class's OkNok method finds which period applies and returns the allow/forbidden.

My problems:

1. How can I make it generic **using `<T>` instead of `<bool>`**.  For example it could return a class or struct that contains 2 booleans and a
   value.
2. If on the way it's possible to make it faster and/or **facilitate easier data entry**.

In the example below if the time is **between t1-t2 it will return true**. between t2-t3 **false**, between t3-t4 **true**, and after t4 **false**.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TimeSpan t1 = new TimeSpan(8, 48, 0);
        TimeSpan t2 = new TimeSpan(9, 56, 0);
        TimeSpan t3 = new TimeSpan(10, 5, 0);
        TimeSpan t4 = new TimeSpan(13, 30, 0);
        TO TO = new TO { Ti = t1, Ok = true, NT = new TO { Ti = t2, Ok = false, NT = new TO { Ti = t3, Ok = true, NT = new TO { Ti = t4, Ok = false } } } };
        Console.WriteLine("The time now is considered " + TO.OkNok(DateTime.Now));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class TO
{
    public TimeSpan Ti;
    public bool Ok;
    public TO NT;
    public bool OkNok(DateTime Time)
    {
        return OkNok(Time.TimeOfDay);
    }
    public bool OkNok(TimeSpan currentTime)
    {
        if (NT == null)
            return Ok;
        else if (currentTime > Ti && currentTime <= NT.Ti)
            return (Ok);
        else return (NT.OkNok(currentTime));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are your classes and other code?

Comment: Ok. Nok...OkNok... don't you get crazy with this code?

Comment: Mainly: I want to fill the chain with T, and return T and not bool. I don't know how.
as for Ok OkNot, you can replace it with whatever makes you happy. Some of the variables (Ti, TN, Ok) are kept short in order to make the inline instantiation short...

Comment: First step is to add a generic parameter to the class definition ``TO<T>``, then you can use it instead of ``bool``.

Comment: Could you please write as code what you want to achieve? Can `T` be of different type for each item in the list? Also, why not using an actual `List<TO>`, and remove the `NT` field. It makes the code a bit cleaner.

Comment: `<T>` is the same for each time. I don't know how to make it as a list, without having a link to the next item inside the class, I don't know how to ask `if (currentTime > Ti && currentTime <= NT.Ti)` inside a foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear to understand, but I hope this helps helps you:

```
//1) I want this class to be able to hold not just a true/false status, but a generic type T, so that it can return more data...
//2) If on the way it's possible to write it in a way that it would run faster and/or facilitate easier data entry.

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        TimeSpan t1 = new TimeSpan(8, 48, 0);
        TimeSpan t2 = new TimeSpan(9, 56, 0);
        TimeSpan t3 = new TimeSpan(10, 5, 0);
        TimeSpan t4 = new TimeSpan(13, 30, 0);
        TO<bool> TO = new TO<bool>(t1, true) {
            new TO<bool>(t2, false) {
                new TO<bool> (t3, true) {
                    new TO<bool>(t4, false)
                }
            }
        };
        Console.WriteLine("The time now is considered " + TO.OkNok(DateTime.Now));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class TO<T> : IEnumerable<TO<T>> {
    public TimeSpan Ti;
    public T Ok;
    public TO<T> NT;

    public TO(TimeSpan timeSpan, T ok) {
        this.Ti = timeSpan;
        this.Ok = ok;
    }

    public T OkNok(DateTime Time) {
        return OkNok(Time.TimeOfDay);
    }

    public T OkNok(TimeSpan currentTime) {
        if(NT == null) {
            return Ok;
        }
        if(currentTime > Ti && currentTime <= NT.Ti) {
            return Ok;
        }
        return NT.OkNok(currentTime);
    }

    public void Add(TO<T> nt) {
        this.NT = nt;
    }

    IEnumerator<TO<T>> IEnumerable<TO<T>>.GetEnumerator() {
        yield return this;
        if(NT != null) {
            yield return NT;
        }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        yield return this;
        if(NT != null) {
            yield return NT;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it helps. It achieves my 2 requests (T, and simplified instantiation). 
Can you explain the magical part? Who calls the Add Method / how can you instantiate one after the other ?

Comment: The "magical" part is the **collection initializer** I implemented (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx). It calls ``Add`` for each entry you specify between the brackets. Having this done, there is also the need to enumerate the elements, as the ``TO`1`` class can be considered now as a collection of ``TO<T>`` elements :)